how can i render dynamically data in filament table
Today I was working on Laravel Filament and I got stuck trying to overwrite the base query of a table dynamically with the help of a filter.
I have a column is_verify in my database, and I want the base query or default data to be where is_verify == 0. I have created a filter called show verify so that when I check this filter, it shows only those records where is_verify == 1 in the user resource.
I tried the following:
return $table
->columns([
    TextColumn::make('name'),
    TextColumn::make('email'),
    TextColumn::make('phone'),
    TextColumn::make('address'),
    TextColumn::make('is_verify')->label('verify')->searchable()
])
->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('is_verify', 0);
})
->filters([
    Filter::make('is_verify')
        ->label('show verify')
        ->query(function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('is_verify', 1);
        }),
]);

This base query works as desired, but when I apply the filter, it shows blank results. I also tried this:
->filters([
Filter::make('is_verify')
    ->baseQuery(fn (Builder $query, User $user) => $query->withoutGlobalScopes([
        $user->Verified()
    ]))
])

User Model:
public function scopeVerified(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->where('is_verify', 1);
}

Can someone help me fix this issue so that the filter works correctly?

You can try:
$query->newQuery()->where('is_verify', 1);

i have applied
            ->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query) {                     $query->where('is_verfiy', 0);             })
and then i try with query method
                Filter::make('is_verify')                 ->query(function (Builder $query) {                     $query->newQuery()->where('is_verify', 1);                 })
and basequery both
Filter::make('is_verify')                     ->baseQuery(fn (Builder $query) => $query->newQuery()->where('is_verify', 1))
But neither approach worked.
